# How to remove excel formula in laravel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel

**I want to upload excel file using laravel and the uploaded excel file should takes only the cell values and not formulas.**

this is my upload code for excel file but i could not find anyhting about save excel file by only values and not formula. I would appreciate your answer anyways. thank you.

````
        if($request){
        return redirect('upload')->with('success','uploaded successfully');
    }else{
        return redirect('upload')->with('fail', 'upload failed');
    }```
````

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [maatwebsite/excel](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).